# Include content of file into plugin (ob_start();;include;ob_get_clean()) without <<<EOT

Tags: plugin-development

I am writing a plugin that requires a large chunk of html. Now the way how it is set up now works.

```
return <<<EOT <html> EOT;
```

But I want to split the file into different php files that i can include. Now I tried this, but it does not work:

```
ob_start();
include(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'file.php');
return ob_get_clean();
```

Any know how this could be done?

=====================
***EDIT***

Ok thanks Chris Carson to I have found the small error, I changed the code to:

```
ob_start();
include(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/file.php');
return ob_get_clean();
```

This is working ok now, except for one small problem.

In the previous code I used something like this:

```
$variable = 'Hello!';

return <<<EOT
    <span>{$variable}</span>
EOT;
```

This would have made the following in html:

```
<span>Hello!</span>
```

But now this:

```
$variable = 'Hello!';

ob_start();
include(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/file.php');
return ob_get_clean();
```

This just prints

```
<span>{$variable}</span>
```

Any way to get the code working with variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including files you don't want the URL, but the filesystem path instead.  So...

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/path/to/myfile.php");
```

Remember to put the first forward slash in `/path/to/myfile.php`, since `dirname` doesn't include the trailing slash.

Comment: AH! yeah of course. Been doing PHP way to long to make such a rookie mistake. Ok but is the ob_start(); method the best way to get the content, or does wordpress have a native function to do this.

Comment: I use ob_start, ob_get_clean -- I don't think there's a WP function for this.